# jQgrid editrules custom_func showing cell value of "select column" in its beginning of error message

Tags: select, jqgrid

I am using editrules custom_func for preventing user to enter same record in jQgrid. I have define custom_func on column whose colMOdel defination are as follows :

`{ name: 'BO', index: 'BO', width: 40, editable: true, edittype: 'select', /*formatter: 'select',*/
                        editrules: { custom: true,
                            custom_func: function (value, colName) {
                                return CustomFunction.call(this, value, colName, oGrid);
                            }
                        },`

I am populating select column of jQgrid as ID(UID) : Name(Text) Its Code perfectly doing his work and showing error message, but problem is error message showing UID value such as

`b66a2719-b88a-427e-8904-816fe8e60fde You are creating duplicate record .
Please give another role for selected BO type.` and I don't want this ID value in its error message. How should I remove this value???? any suggestions???

Comment: Which editing mode you use? Which version of jqGrid use use? Do you tried the same in the current 4.5.4 version of jqGrid?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using Inline editing and my jQgrid version is 4.4.4... Nope I have not try in version 4.5.4...

Comment: **Which editing mode you use?** The version 4.4.4 is about 8 months old. I recommend you to try the current 4.5.4 version of jqGrid published yesterday. The close problem which you described was in inline editing, but it should be fixed already in the current jqGrid version.

Comment: That means this problem will not solve in my jQgrid version...?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Moreover you should answer the question which I asked you twice.

Comment: I have already gave answer above... I am using **Inline Editing**...

Comment: Sorry, I skipped it during the reading. I explained in my answer why you should update jqGrid to new version of make changes of your copy of jqGrid code.

Comment: Ok Oleg sir... Thanx for your useful suggestions.... Keep supporting.. take care...

Answer (score 0):

You have to update jqGrid to new version to fix the problem. The reason is very easy. The inline editing module used in jqGrid 4.4.4 the following lines (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L209-L213))

```js
cv = $.jgrid.checkValues(tmp[nm],i,$t);
if(cv[0] === false) {
    cv[1] = tmp[nm] + " " + cv[1];
    return false;
}
```

where `tmp[nm]` contains in your case the text `b66a2719-b88a-427e-8904-816fe8e60fde`. jqGrid 4.5.2 uses the same code. So one have no way to remove the prefixing `tmp[nm] + " "`.

Recently published version 4.5.4 changes the lines to the following (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L219-L222)).

```js
cv = $.jgrid.checkValues.call($t,tmp[nm],i);
if(cv[0] === false) {
    return false;
}
```

So you have to update jqGrid to 4.5.4 or to make the corresponding changes in your copy of jqGrid code.